# How to scale armature and mesh proportionally?

Tags: armature

I want to keep the original mesh scale to 1.0, which means I can't scale the armature in object mode.

is there any way I can scale in both edit mode proportionally?

Comment: You can just apply the scale after the you change it. I can't remember the shortcut, but the space and search should be able to find it.

Comment: the shortcut is [ctrl]+[a]